# What's the shortest way to bind variable $this to a callable object field?

Tags: php, closures, this, stdclass

I bound the `$this` variable with `Closure::bind()` method (lines 12-13) to my `getName()` and `getAge()` methods (lines 4 and 7) so that they can refer to their own member fields (lines 2-3) in an instance of `stdClass`. It works, but I find this a bit tedious.

Is there any special variable or built-in function that I can refer to the current instance of `stdClass` inside my `getName()` and `getAge()` methods (lines 4 and 7) without calling `Closure::bind()` method? Or, is there any workaround to this, if any?

**PHP Code**

```php
$human = (object) [
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'age'  => 25,
    'getName' => function() {
        var_dump($this->name);
    },
    'getAge' => function() {
        var_dump($this->age);
    },
];

$human->getName = Closure::bind($human->getName, $human);
$human->getAge = Closure::bind($human->getAge, $human);

print_r($human);

($human->getName)();
($human->getAge)();
```

**Sample Output**:

```text
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => John Doe
    [age] => 25
    [getName] => Closure Object
        (
            [this] => stdClass Object
 *RECURSION*
        )

    [getAge] => Closure Object
        (
             [this] => stdClass Object
 *RECURSION*
        )

)
string(8) "John Doe"
int(25)
```

Comment: Considering that all properties in the stdClass are public, why bother with getter methods? If you want to use a class with some specific logic, just create a class with the functionality you want instead of trying to modify stdClass.

Comment: It might be useful in some special cases but not necessarily for a getter method, for obvious reasons. I could iterate through the result of  `get_object_vars()` to dynamically bind the methods to variable `$this`, but it would be nice if there is some special variable that points to the current instance of `stdClass`.

Comment: This sounds like a silly problem to want to solve. Why not just write your own class?

Comment: It would probably overkill to use a class declaration if one just needs a single custom object to pass as an argument.

Comment: Why overkill? PHP has [anonymous classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) just for this occasion.

Comment: Lets just focus on `stdClass`. Why does instances of `stdClass` does not have a reference of its own inside the object? Is all instances of `stdClass` `$this`-less?

Comment: I added a second solution to my answer.

Comment: `stdClass` has no methods. You are creating an `stdClass` with fields containing closures; unlike JavaScript, fields containing closures are not the same as methods. (Methods and fields in fact live in separate namespaces, though this isn’t immediately visible.) The closures don’t have any `$this` to close over, and when you invoke them, it doesn’t matter that you extracted them from an object. If you *subclassed* `stdClass`, you could add actual methods that would receive the object as `$this` when invoked.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: despite the question body calling them such, `getName` and `getAge` are *not* methods.  In PHP, methods and fields live in separate namespaces: methods are always looked up on the class, whereas fields are looked up on the instance.  If the call expressions looked like `$human->getName()` and `$human->getAge()` instead of `($human->getName)()` and `($human->getAge)()`, they would be looking up the corresponding `stdClass` *methods*, which of course don’t exist, so they would fail.

Furthermore, once a field value is read, the object where it was read from is discarded and not used any further; it makes no difference that the value obtained happens to be callable.  Because the object is discarded, there is nothing to bind the `$this` variable to inside the closure.  This is unlike JavaScript, where methods are exactly equivalent to fields, they share a single namespace, and invoking a function just looked up on an object binds that object as `this` within the invoked function’s body.

I think what you *actually* want to accomplish is best achieved with an [anonymous class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php):

```
$human = new class {
    public $name = 'John Doe';
    public $age = 25;

    public function getName() {
        var_dump($this->name);
    }

    public function getAge() {
        var_dump($this->age);
    }
};

$human->getName();
$human->getAge();
```

This makes `getName` and `getAge` *actually* methods, which receive the appropriate `$this` binding.

You can even make your anonymous class a subclass of `stdClass` if you insist, though I see no particular reason why.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I thought `stdClass` were relatively similar to object literals in JavaScript. Well, I was wrong. Anyway, thank you for clarifying about closures. I was just exploring the limits of `stdClass`.

Comment: Yeah, I though you were coming from another language. Javascript is very different from PHP in many ways, it serves a different purpose. Trying to apply Javascript programming patterns to PHP might not be a good idea. I much prefer this anonymous class example, and the next step would be to use a more general **named class** for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a better case for why you would want to do this. That said, the `Closure::bind()` is indeed a bit tedious. There is something you can do, but I doubt you will like it. It goes like this:

```
$human = (object) [
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'age'  => 25,
    'getName' => function($object) {
        var_dump($object->name);
    },
    'getAge' => function($object) {
        var_dump($object->age);
    },
];

($human->getName)($human);
($human->getAge)($human);
```

See: [PHP fiddle](https://3v4l.org/BdVb2)

Here you admit that, at the time of creation, the functions aren't aware that they are part of an object, when `$this` would make sense. Therefore you supply the needed object later as an argument, and everything is fine.

Again, creating a normal class would be preferable, if only because it is easier to understand. Remember, you write code to do something, but also because it is a way to communicate your intent to yourself and others.

I thought of another way to do this. Also not what you want, but it kind of works:

```
$human = (object) [
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'age'  => 25,
    'getName' => function() {
        global $human;
        var_dump($human->name);
    },
    'getAge' => function() {
        global $human;
        var_dump($human->age);
    },
];

($human->getName)();
($human->getAge)();
```

See: [PHP fiddle](https://3v4l.org/Z9pN7)

Comment: Yah. This is exactly my first try, then i used `Closure::bind()` to avoid passing the instance of `stdClass` for every method call.

Comment: @TheGoodGameLife I agree that it is not nice that `$human` has to be supplied as an argument, but unless you can make a better case for turning an array into an object, and using `$this` in this manner, I think this is as good as it is going to get. Context of a question can be important. For now `getName` is a property of your object, and cannot be expected to act as a valid method of that object, without some real fiddling.

Comment: Your second solution is much appreciated! Thanks. Although the `$human` variable won't be flexible in between scope . I completely forgot about that `global` keyword.